# Hardware Requirements for my Exchange 2007 Environment

Tags: exchange, server-setup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

I have a 2000 user base in Exchange 2007, with 6 databases, the biggest one is 300GB. In our ccr environment, we have 2 MB, 2 HT, and 2 CAS servers. What would be the best hardware recommendation for this setup?? How much memory and CPU's should each server have for optimal performance?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't really judge your requirements from this kind of information. You need somebody experienced to get their hands on the system and do some benchmarking, or at least know the current environment and observe its bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here for some guidelines:
[Exchange 2007 Sizing Cheat Sheed](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2007/planning-architecture/exchange-2007-sizing-cheat-sheet.html)

You probably could co-locate the HT role with the CAS or MBX role.

But the real question would be: Are you currently suffering any performance hits? Or why do you ask?

Comment: I having many users complain lately about speeds and performance in Outlook 2010, such as when they select a folder, it takes the server several minutes for the folder to display the items. Sometimes Outlook will freeze while waiting to load, and it takes several minutes to unfreeze. They are terminal users, and are not in cached mode

Comment: @user1236435 So you need to run performance monitor on the TS server and the exchange servers in order to determine the bottlenecks that are impacting the users, and address them properly. You'll find this works much better than randomly changing things. If you want "optimal performance" then you need to define what that means to you.